# ResultSet doesn't return all the values

Tags: java, oracle, resultset

I am loading to a database table 8000 records about the users and I am making some operations on that data and at the end I want to receive back my 8000 records with balance. My code:

```
public void getBalance(String database){
    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    try{
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
           conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@address","user","password");
          stmt=conn.createStatement();
          rs=stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from balance1");
          int count=0;
          while(rs.next()){
            count=rs.getInt(1);
           }
           System.out.println("The count is "+count);
           conn.setAutoCommit(false);
           stmt.setFetchSize(count);    
           rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from balanceview");
           writeToAFile(rs);
    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
        if(conn!=null){
            try{
                conn.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                _logger.severe(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }if(stmt!=null){
            try{
                stmt.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                _logger.severe(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }if(rs!=null){
            try{
                rs.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                _logger.severe(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am facing a problem only 2000 values are returned back. Is there a way to return all 8000 values.

Comment: What is `count=rs.getInt(1)` *supposed* to do? Should it be `count++` instead? I would also suggest that `stmt.setFetchSize(count)` isn't a fabulous idea unless you have a ton of RAM to throw at this...

Comment: You are selecting the count from `balance1` but are querying `balanceview` afterwards. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes balance1 is my table where all 8000 customers are stored and balanceview is just a view that contains simple select on balance1 table

Comment: count=rs.getInt(1) returns number of rows in a balance1 table

Comment: Well try querying directly from `balance1` so that we know the problem isn't related to the view.

Comment: What is the value of your `count` variable after first select?

Comment: @user3428496 Yes, I've just noticed. I was thrown by the while loop - if I'm only expecting one row I would use an `if` statement instead of a loop to retrieve it. My comment about the fetch size still stands though - is there a particular reason you want to hold that many rows in memory at the same time?

Comment: @Tunaki just tried still doesn't work

Comment: What does `select count(1) from balanceview` return?

Comment: Try to create a new fresh statement with `stmt=conn.createStatement();` before the second select.

Comment: @JonK there is no reason for that at the beginning I did not have it but then when it did not work I started searching in google and found this thought it might help but it did not

Comment: Ok - ResultSets stream their data from the database when you access them. They hold a certain number of rows in memory (default is 10) before they need to go back to the database to get the next set of rows. Setting the fetch size to 8000 means it will hold 8000 rows of data in memory, **not** that you will get 8000 rows of data back from the database.

Comment: `setFetchSize()` does **not** control the number of rows returned by the query. Are you maybe confusing that with `setMaxRows()` which *does* limit the number of rows returned

Comment: You're closing everything in the wrong order. It should be the opposite order from the order of acquisition. ResultSet, then Statement, then Connection.

Comment: setFetchSize will not limit your resultset, IT IS NOT LIMIT QUERY. Try to do a select query for balanceview directly in DB and see the count, it may be same as whatever you are getting with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JDBC will always fetches default number of rows (not the entire result set) to your local memory. Once you reach at the last line of the fetched rows (say by doing next() and try to access next row) and if there are more rows in the result, then another round-trip call will be made to the database to fetch next batch of rows to local memory.

Even you can set number of rows you want fetch in local memory than usual, you may consider CachedRowSet.

When you set the fetchSize() on the Statement, you are only giving a instruction to the JDBC driver how much you want it should fetch, but JDBC driver is free to ignore your instructions. I do not know what the Oracle driver does with the fetchSize(). Most of times its observed that MySQL JDBC driver will always fetch all rows unless you set the fetchSize() to Integer.MIN_VALUE but this is not the case with Oracle Database.